# React Hook keeps throwing error missing dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'callback' and 'isSubmit'.
Trying to validate a registration form but I get this error still a noob to React please help

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useForm = (callback, validate) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    });

    // Handle Errors
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})
    const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false)


    // Hold entered input
    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    // Prevent Form from submitting
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setErrors(validate(values));
        setIsSubmit(true);
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
          if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
            callback();
          }
        },
        [errors]
      );

  return {handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors};
};

export default useForm;
```

Am working on simple registration form and I cant' wrap my head around why this react is throwing this particular error message. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just add those variables as dependencies to the last `useEffect` from your hook.

```js
    useEffect(
        () => {
          if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
            callback();
          }
        },
        [errors, callback, isSubmit]
      );
```

Comment: I'm getting this now
TypeError: callback is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can drive away this warning as emartini's answer above, but I'm wondering why you need the useEffect. Can we achieve the same thing by not using useEffect. Something likes this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useForm = (callback, validate) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    });

    // Handle Errors
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

    // Hold entered input
    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    // Prevent Form from submitting
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const validateErrors= validate(values);
        if (Object.keys(validateErrors).length === 0) {
          callback();
        }
        setErrors(validateErrors);

    };

  return {handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors};
};

export default useForm;
```

Comment: Thanks like I said I'm still a noob, gave yours a try and this error popped up Line 34:11:  Parsing error: Identifier 'errors' has already been declared

Comment: oops, just need to rename the variable :        const validateErrors= validate(values);

Comment: TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: this means you are not passing callback as a function in which u use useForm. make sure the first parameter you pass in useForm is a function.